# Query string gets chopped off using ImageResizer remotereader plugin

Tags: imageresizer

I'm working with URLs like:

> mysite.com/export/media.ashx?MediaID=d011f09ad9c443c9b539b4d4b6b6cc10

When I build URLs like this, I lose the query string from the remote site, e.g. "?MediaID=..." gets chopped off:

> http://localhost:57704/remote/mysite.com/export/media.ashx?MediaID=d011f09ad9c443c9b539b4d4b6b6cc10?preset=ListingCarousel

Comment: You have to use the encoded URL form, not the human-readable format if you're mixing query strings. 

http://imageresizing.net/docs/v4/plugins/remotereader

Comment: Thanks. I’d come across that as well. For various reasons unrelated to this issue, since we control the remote server, a rewrite rule there provided a formatted path that worked.